# How to check a group of solutions of partial differential equations?

Tags: list-manipulation, replacement

There is the partial differential equations,
$$
\left.\left\{\begin{array}{c}u_t-3qu^2u_x+\frac{3}{2}q(uv)_x-\frac{1}{4}qu_{xxx}=0,\\v_t+\frac{3}{2}qvv_x-3q(u^2v)_x+3qu_xu_{xx}+\frac{3}{2}quu_{xxx}-\frac{1}{4}qv_{xxx}=0,\quad q(\neq0)\in\mathbb{R}.\end{array}\right.\right.
$$

```
eqns = {D[u[x, t], t] - 
     3*q*u[x, t]^2*D[u[x, t], x] + (3/2)*q*
      D[u[x, t]*v[x, t], x] - (1/4)*q*D[u[x, t], {x, 3}] == 0, 
   D[v[x, t], t] + (3/2)*q*v[x, t]*D[v[x, t], x] - 
     3*q*u[x, t]^2*D[v[x, t], x] + 
     3*q*D[u[x, t], x]*D[u[x, t], {x, 2}] + (3/2)*q*u[x, t]*
      D[u[x, t], {x, 3}] - (1/4)*q*D[v[x, t], {x, 3}] == 0};
```

I want to check a group of solutions in partial differential equations,My previous program produced the following results,

```
solution1 = {{a0 -> 0, a1 -> -1, b0 -> -1, b1 -> 0, b2 -> 1,c -> -q}, 
{a0 -> -(1/2), a1 -> -(1/2), b0 -> -(1/2), b1 -> 0, b2 -> 1/2, c -> -q}, 
{a0 -> 0, a1 -> -(1/2), b0 -> -(1/2), b1 -> 0,b2 -> 1/2, c -> -(q/4)}, 
{a0 -> 1/2, a1 -> -(1/2), b0 -> -(1/2), b1 -> 0, b2 -> 1/2, c -> -q}, 
{a0 -> -(1/2), a1 -> 1/2, b0 -> -(1/2), b1 -> 0, b2 -> 1/2, c -> -q}, 
{a0 -> 0, a1 -> 1/2, b0 -> -(1/2), b1 -> 0, b2 -> 1/2, c -> -(q/4)}, 
{a0 -> 1/2, a1 -> 1/2, b0 -> -(1/2), b1 -> 0, b2 -> 1/2, c -> -q}, 
{a0 -> 0, a1 -> 1, b0 -> -1, b1 -> 0, b2 -> 1, c -> -q}}
```

where

```
u[x_, t_] := a0 + a1 Tanh[x - ct]
v[x_, t_] := b0 + b1Tanh[x - ct] + b2Tanh[x - ct]^2
```

First, I took the values of the coefficients in each solution from solution1, and substituted them into the functions `u` and `v`, and finally generated a list(I actually did not use `u` and 'v').

```
soluList = 
 Table[{a0 + a1 Tanh[x - c t], 
    b0 + b1 Tanh[x - c t] + b2 Tanh[x - c t]^2} /. sol, {sol, 
   solution1}]

(* {{-Tanh[q*t + x], -1 + 
   Tanh[q*t + x]^2}, {-(1/2) - (1/2)*Tanh[q*t + x], -(1/2) + (1/2)*
    Tanh[q*t + x]^2}, 
   {(-(1/2))*
   Tanh[(q*t)/4 + x], -(1/2) + (1/2)*Tanh[(q*t)/4 + x]^2}, {1/
    2 - (1/2)*Tanh[q*t + x], -(1/2) + (1/2)*Tanh[q*t + x]^2}, 
   {-(1/2) + (1/2)*Tanh[q*t + x], -(1/2) + (1/2)*
    Tanh[q*t + x]^2}, {(1/2)*
   Tanh[(q*t)/4 + x], -(1/2) + (1/2)*Tanh[(q*t)/4 + x]^2}, 
   {1/2 + (1/2)*Tanh[q*t + x], -(1/2) + (1/2)*Tanh[q*t + x]^2}, {Tanh[
   q*t + x], -1 + Tanh[q*t + x]^2}} *)
```

Finally I tried to make a module to hold the verifying process, but it outputs an error,

```
verifySolutions2[sol_, eqns_] := 
  Module[{uSol, vSol, eqn1, eqn2, verifiedEqn1, verifiedEqn2},
   {uSol, vSol} = sol;
   eqn1 = eqns[[1]] /. {u[x, t] -> uSol, v[x, t] -> vSol};
   eqn2 = eqns[[2]] /. {u[x, t] -> uSol, v[x, t] -> vSol};
   verifiedEqn1 = Simplify[eqn1 == 0];
   verifiedEqn2 = Simplify[eqn2 == 0];
   {verifiedEqn1, verifiedEqn2}];


verifiedSolutions = Map[verifySolutions2[#, eqns] &, soluList]

(* Something like that it's too long, so I copy the first one
{(4*Derivative[0, 1][u][x, t] == 
    q*(6*(1 + Tanh[q*t + x]^2)*Derivative[1, 0][u][x, t] + 
       6*Tanh[q*t + x]*Derivative[1, 0][v][x, t] + 
              Derivative[3, 0][u][x, t])) == 
  0, (4*Derivative[0, 1][v][x, t] == 
    q*(6*(1 + Tanh[q*t + x]^2)*Derivative[1, 0][v][x, t] + 
              
       12*Derivative[1, 0][u][x, 
         t]*(2*Sech[q*t + x]^2*Tanh[q*t + x] - 
          Derivative[2, 0][u][x, t]) + 
       6*Tanh[q*t + x]*Derivative[3, 0][u][x, t] + 
              Derivative[3, 0][v][x, t])) == 0}, *)
```

I find Mathematica’s handling of Replace operations to be quite tricky to a beginner like me, and I’m hoping to get some help. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You should not plugin solutions into the ode or the pde. The standard way to verify solution generated by DSolve is given in [howtoCheckTheResultsOfDSolve](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/howto/CheckTheResultsOfDSolve.html)  so you can use this method for your solutions by iterating over each one.

Comment: What I meant is you should use the `Function` form to plugin the solution into the ode or pde as explained in the above link.

Comment: @Nasser I understand, so my work now is making `{-Tanh[q*t + x], -1 + 
   Tanh[q*t + x]^2}` to the `Function` form of `u` and `v` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I mean like this

```
eqns = {D[u[x, t], t] - 
     3*q*u[x, t]^2*D[u[x, t], x] + (3/2)*q*
      D[u[x, t]*v[x, t], x] - (1/4)*q*D[u[x, t], {x, 3}] == 0, 
   D[v[x, t], t] + (3/2)*q*v[x, t]*D[v[x, t], x] - 
     3*q*u[x, t]^2*D[v[x, t], x] + 
     3*q*D[u[x, t], x]*D[u[x, t], {x, 2}] + (3/2)*q*u[x, t]*
      D[u[x, t], {x, 3}] - (1/4)*q*D[v[x, t], {x, 3}] == 0};

solV = v -> Function[{x, t}, b0 + b1*Tanh[x - c*t] + b2*Tanh[x - c*t]^2]
solU = u -> Function[{x, t}, a0 + a1  Tanh[x - c*t]]

solution1 = {{a0 -> 0, a1 -> -1, b0 -> -1, b1 -> 0, b2 -> 1, 
    c -> -q}, {a0 -> -(1/2), a1 -> -(1/2), b0 -> -(1/2), b1 -> 0, 
    b2 -> 1/2, c -> -q}, {a0 -> 0, a1 -> -(1/2), b0 -> -(1/2), 
    b1 -> 0, b2 -> 1/2, c -> -(q/4)}, {a0 -> 1/2, a1 -> -(1/2), 
    b0 -> -(1/2), b1 -> 0, b2 -> 1/2, c -> -q}, {a0 -> -(1/2), 
    a1 -> 1/2, b0 -> -(1/2), b1 -> 0, b2 -> 1/2, c -> -q}, {a0 -> 0, 
    a1 -> 1/2, b0 -> -(1/2), b1 -> 0, b2 -> 1/2, 
    c -> -(q/4)}, {a0 -> 1/2, a1 -> 1/2, b0 -> -(1/2), b1 -> 0, 
    b2 -> 1/2, c -> -q}, {a0 -> 0, a1 -> 1, b0 -> -1, b1 -> 0, 
    b2 -> 1, c -> -q}};
```

Now to verify using the first set of parameters do

```
 eqns /. {solV /. solution1[[1]],solU /. solution1[[1]]} // FullSimplify
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

So it verified the `v` solution but the `u` solution did not verify. To do all:

```
Map[(eqns /. {solV /. #, solU /. #} // FullSimplify) &, solution1] // Column
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

It looks like your `u` solution is wrong. But `v` is correct.

Watch the spacing. `ct` is not same as `c t`. did you mean to give `q` some value also?

Comment: Thank you greatly! yes I found it is different in `Function` between `ct` and `c t`, `q`is a nonzero real constant.After running your code, my result is `{True, True}` ,maybe there is a typo in my answer.